# How to parse "steps" from the google directions API to java (android)

Tags: java, android, json, google-directions-api

I'm a complete beginner, especially when is comes to JSON parsing.

I've been using the google directions API 
to make a basic navigation app that draws a route from two locations, which is all great. However after trying for hours to parse the "steps" from the API, I still can't make it work.

I've used this example https://github.com/hiepxuan2008/GoogleMapDirectionSimple
to parse the JSON to draw the route.

This is done in the following code. (full code on github "Directionfinder.java")

```
private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
    if (data == null)
        return;

    List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
        Route route = new Route();

        JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
        JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
        JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
        JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
        JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");

        route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
        route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
        route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
        route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
        route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
        route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
        route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

        routes.add(route);
    }

    listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
}
```

Heres how the JSON typically looks. http://pastebin.com/czYkBWWU

I need to parse "maneuver", "start_location", "distance", "start_location and the position from every step of a given route.

It seems fairly easy to parse this, but I just can't figure out how.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is full code. I Run it in my Device and get Successfull result. If you face problem then let me know.

```
try {
            List<Route> routes=new ArrayList<Route>();

            JSONObject mainJSON=new JSONObject(jsonJ);
            JSONArray jarray1=mainJSON.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject jobj1=jarray1.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray jarray2=jobj1.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject jobj2=jarray2.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray stepArray=jobj2.getJSONArray("steps");

            for (int i=0;i<stepArray.length();i++){
                Route route=new Route();

                JSONObject jobj5=stepArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject disOBJ=jobj5.getJSONObject("distance");
                JSONObject durOBJ=jobj5.getJSONObject("duration");
                JSONObject endOBJ=jobj5.getJSONObject("end_location");
                JSONObject polOBJ=jobj5.getJSONObject("polyline");
                JSONObject startOBJ=jobj5.getJSONObject("start_location");

                route.startAddress=jobj2.getString("start_address");
                route.endAddress=jobj2.getString("end_address");

                if (jobj5.has("maneuver")){
                    route.maneuver=new Maneuver(jobj5.getString("maneuver"));
                }

                route.distance=new Distance(disOBJ.getString("text"),disOBJ.getString("value"));
                route.duration=new Duration(durOBJ.getString("text"),durOBJ.getString("value"));
                route.startLocation=new LatLng(startOBJ.getDouble("lat"),startOBJ.getDouble("lng"));
                route.endLocation=new LatLng(endOBJ.getDouble("lat"),endOBJ.getDouble("lng"));
                route.points=decodePoluLine(polOBJ.getString("points"));

                routes.add(route);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I tried to implement the code, and did some minor changes to make it compile, and I get following exception :  "org.json.JSONException: No value for steps". So it seems that i did something wrong. The edited method is in this pastebin, if you would be so kind to have another look [link] (http://pastebin.com/s77Cd4SU)

Comment: In which line? Your json response shows that your required values are in Steps array

Comment: line 113. which is JSONArray jarray3 = Leg.getJSONArray("steps"); . I tried to put "maneuver" in instead in the pastebin, but it gives the same result

Comment: I wrote jarray3= jarray2.getjsonArray()

Comment: Yeah, that gives "getJSONarray (int)     in JSONArray cannot be applied to (java.lang.string)

Comment: And the IDE suggest that i parse it as an int?

Comment: U used jarray3=jarray2.getJSONArray("steps")?

Comment: Yes. The IDE underlines both "steps" and "legs"

Comment: JSONArray jarray1=jData.getJSONArray("routes");
  JSONArray jarray2=jarray1.getJSONArray("legs");
  JSONArray jarray3=jarray2.getJSONArray("steps");

Comment: when attempting to compile this i get Error:(111, 52) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Comment: Try jarray2=jarray1.getJSONArray(1); and jarray3=jarray2.getJSONArray(5);

Comment: Thanks you for helping me! That gives a JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)

Comment: I don't have laptop right now, I looked into it tomorrow. It is hard to solve from mobile.

Comment: Wow, that's actually impressive. Thanks a lot, i really do appreciate your help. If you need it, an updated version of the method : http://pastebin.com/3d5D9LaH

Comment: YES ! Thanks! It works perfectly now. REALLY, this made my day. Thanks alot. I'm sort of new here, have I accepted your response OK, or is there another thing I have to do, to credit you properly. good day!